# Generating synthetic social networks?

Tags: java, python, algorithm, language-agnostic, graph

I have come across a number of social network analysis tools but I was wondering if there are any libraries that let you generate synthetic social networks like the Watts and Strogatz model or the Barabási-Albert Scale-Free networks or a network dependent on the Caveman model. Whatever I have come across are either pure algorithms or implementations in Fortran which is not really my language of expertise.

What I am currently looking for is a way to set the properties of the social network and be able to generate a synthetic network (adjacency list perhaps) for further analysis. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this article can help? http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lakoglu/pubs/kdd09-utility-model.pdf

Comment: @p.marino: Thank you. Looks like a very nice paper. Currently reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) package has a number of [random graph generation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generators.html) methods.

Comment: I think of random graph generation when I read about this problem as well.

Comment: +1 Yeap. You're absolutely right. I somehow missed the random graph part in the documentation of networkx. Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

[igraph](http://igraph.org/) supports the network models you mention. It has C, Python and R wrappers.  If you want to develop more sophisticated / realistic social networks you could specify an [ergm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ergm/index.html) model and simulate from it using the [statnet R packages](http://www.statnet.org/).